# Ubuntu 23.10 keeps inconsistently blocking incoming connections (from machines on the same subnet)

Tags: networking, server, firewall

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 23.10. It's running on a PC at home, and is only Wi-Fi connected. I've enabled ufw, and have allowed web traffic as I'm using this to mock up a Wordpres site for someone. I only need to be able to view this website from within my home.

The PC has a static IP on the Wi-Fi adapter, and can always browse the internet.

However, being able to access the website running on this is very hit and miss. It seems to work for a short while, then if I don't do anything with it, I lose access.

Even rebooting doesn't allow incoming traffic again (at least not immediately).

The website is always available on the local machine by it's IP address.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: It would help get better answers if you describe step by step what you do and what you see/expect to see.